# React navigation 5 custom header component causes crash when opening published app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-elements

I want to have my own **header** component in **React navigation 5**. Everything is working fine in **development** and **production** mode however, when I build the project, open it on my phone and press the following 'Settings' screen it gives me **no error log** and crashes my app. I am using **react native elements** as a custom header component.

Versions that I am using:

- react-navigation/bottom-tabs ^5.4.5
- react-navigation/native ^5.4.0
- react-navigation/stack ^5.3.7
- expo-linear-gradient ~8.2.1

I already deconstructed some things and came to the conclusion that the following code is not working

```
       <Stack.Navigator 
        screenOptions={{
            header: () => (
                <Header
                    leftComponent={{ text: 'Settings', style: [t.textWhite] }}
                    rightComponent={<Icon name='user' type='font-awesome' color={'white'} />}
                    linearGradientProps={{
                        colors: ['#2c5282', '#3b8b85'],
                        start: { x: 0, y: 0.5 },
                        end: { x: 1, y: 0.5 },
                      }}
                />
            ),
        }}
        initialRouteName="SettingsIndex"
    >
```

Anyone knows how to solve?

**EDIT (found issue)**

The issue was caused by the 'linearGradientProps' in my header property. So either this could be an react-native-elements or react-nativation crash.

```
linearGradientProps={{
   colors: ['#2c5282', '#3b8b85'],
   start: { x: 0, y: 0.5 },
   end: { x: 1, y: 0.5 },
}}
```

Comment: Try to rebuild with debug and check crash maybe you miss https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Comment: @AnhDevit I am using expo's version of gradients

Comment: where is your import header?

Comment: @AnhDevit on top but not the issue of the code.

Comment: @AnhDevit My app crashes only when I add gradients.

Comment: yes, can you show you code you import header?

Comment: @AnhDevit import {Header} from 'react-native-elements';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I think you don't read the document carefully
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/header/#lineargradient-usage
This is example you miss LinearGradient

```
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

...

<Header
  ViewComponent={LinearGradient} // Don't forget this!
  linearGradientProps={{
    colors: ['red', 'pink'],
    start: { x: 0, y: 0.5 },
    end: { x: 1, y: 0.5 },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I will try to read the docs better this time, thank you :)